# adding text formatting by thymeleaf form

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I want to create a form which adds some content to the website.

I use Spring MVC with Thymeleaf view. How I can realize ordered or unordered lists in the adding content? Also I want to get ability to do another text formatting, like bold, italic and so on (in the new content which will be added my my form).

Comment: Can you please post some example code?  If you're looking to print an ordered or unordered list, see the HTML tags `<ul>` and `<ol>`.  See `<strong>` for bold, etc.

Comment: Data-th-utext and wysiwyg editor on js. Solved.